# How to secure Angular (accessType- Public) and Nodejs app (accesType- bearer-only) with keyCloak

Tags: node.js, angular, keycloak, okta

i am trying to integrate keyCloak in my application, i have created a Realm name "my-app" and added 2 clients

1. frontend (accessType -public)
2. backend (accessType -  bearer-only)

I want to use the access token (returned from frontend client) to authenticate backend APIs.

i want to achieve same thing explained in this tutorial by making use of Roles, Client Scopes and mappers but not working for me

https://medium.com/devops-dudes/secure-front-end-react-js-and-back-end-node-js-express-rest-api-with-keycloak-daf159f0a94e

Comment: Please read the stackoverflow guideline how to write the question. Please put the necessary code, if required. That will help to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

i made a mistake in configuration,

on frontend side i made url for auth server "http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth" and on Server side it was "http://localhost:8080/auth", else everything was correct